# How can I make a !say command for a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

I can't seem to figure out how to make my bot say the message content without the prefix (!say).
I probably need to add the prefix somehow else, but I don't know where. Also, how can I do so that
I make the bot say something in a specific channel?
This is my code right now:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith('!say'):
    await message.channel.send(message.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, import all the libraries:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Then, set a prefix in this manner:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

After that, you can use the following code:

```py
@bot.command(name='say')
async def say(ctx, *, content):
    await ctx.send(content)
```

Comment: You don't need to define both `client` and `bot`. If you plan on using commands, then `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for some reason, it still does not work. The command I have to use in discord is !say <massage> right?

Comment: yes, your prefix has already been defined

Answer (score 0):

The following command takes ctx and the content of the message as the parameter/arguement. So even if you are writing more than a single word, the bot is going to send the exact same thing and not just the first word

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, content): #content will be the message you want the bot to say
  await ctx.send(content)
```

Also be sure to use `client.command()` as you have defined `client` as the discord bot